# How to make one function that takes two different values ​and generates a key in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, key

For example you have two mail accounts,I want give these two e-mail accounts to a function and receive a unique key word for these two emails.But there is a problem, when I change mail locations I have to get the same result again.

```
def two_mails(test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com):
    #algorithm codes
    return "one_key"
```

Another time I have to use this function and generate this key.

```
if two_mails(test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com) == "one_key":
    #Other codes
```

Even if I change email locations, I need to get the same key

```
if two_mails(test2@gmail.com, test@gmail.com) == "one_key":
    #Other codes
```

They should be able to create different keys with different mails.

```
def two_mails(different@gmail.com, different2@gmail.com):
    #algorithm codes
    return "different_key"
```

Please write the sample code while writing your idea.

EDITED#

I need to generate a key for these two mails and use it as id in db. I need to be able to do db query with this key when I need it. `two_mails(different@gmail.com, different2@gmail.com)`.but sometimes mails change location `two_mails(different2@gmail.com, different@gmail.com)`. What I need is to get the same result even if the mail locations change

Comment: what kind of constraints do you have on the produced key (fixed size, as in most hash functions etc...)? If none, you can just sort and concatenate the input strings together.

Comment: no constraints.Can you write sample code?When we change the location of mail addresses, it should give the same result

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: First, you can't use `@` in a parameter name. Second, it appears you want to pass literal e-mail addresses as arguments, so you need to use `str`s: `if two_mails("test@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com")` == "one_key":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function which takes the email address strings and sorts them and joins them as a single string and returns the hash.

So that if the positions are interchanged it gives the same output as after the sorting operation the order of the strings are maintained all the time:

```
import hashlib
def getUniquekey(*, first_email, second_email):
    data = "".join(sorted([first_email, second_email]))
    return hashlib.md5(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

print(getUniquekey(first_email="foo@yahoo.com", second_email="bar@yahoo.com"))
print(getUniquekey(first_email="bar@yahoo.com", second_email="foo@yahoo.com"))
```

Output:

```
c8cd4cdcd95e12c043fef21c0fb07a9f
c8cd4cdcd95e12c043fef21c0fb07a9f
```

Comment: worked well but produces different output each time. I want to save the output to db and then query it with this key. Therefore, it should give the same output every time the function runs.

Comment: @RaghimNajafov we can use md5 hash from the `hashlib` module instead of the `hash()` that would be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort your 2 email adresses before creating a key by internal hashing function of the 2-uple (email1,email2), the key will be consistant.

Answer (score 0):

You have restricted your function to `test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com` as arguments, if what you need is to parse different arguments to your function at every call, you'll need to include parameters:

```
def two_mails(first_email, second_email):
#make sure to replace test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com with first_email, second_email throughout your functio
#algorithm codes
return "one_key"
```

and whenever you need to call the function, you can parse whatever appropriate arguments into it